# proxy connect aborted curl

Tags: php, curl

i am using proxy to connect to whatsApp server but i am always keep getting this error  **proxy connect aborted** what i am missing ??? any idea ?

```
        $proxy_server = '60.12.11.39';
        $proxy_port = '1080';
        // Configure the connection.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,$proxy_server.':'. $proxy_port);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT,"1080"); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, Constants::WHATSAPP_USER_AGENT);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: text/json'));
        // This makes CURL accept any peer!
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        // Close the connection.
            if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
            {
                echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
            }

        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Also try using this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same non descriptive error while trying to connect through a proxy for a different purpose. This is what solved it for me:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);`

You have to define the right proxy type for it to work. It defaults to CURLPROXY_HTTP and the options are CURLPROXY_SOCKS4, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5, CURLPROXY_SOCKS4A or CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME.

Comment: I have the same problem, but tried all those options without luck. Could you share other curl_setopt() sentences you have used before/after setting CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, just in case they must go in a particular order? Thanks

Comment: curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4); // this is required for google apis because ipv6 is not supported
Other CURLOPT_ that I also set  that I don't think matter directly in this case: CAINFO='cacert.pem', FOLLOWLOCATION=1, VERBOSE=TRUE, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT=TRUE,